# Error Using Google Chrome in Selenium VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having problems setting up Selenium for VBA.

I've already tried to install and uninstall, but the same error appears.

**"Run-time Error -2146233088 (80131500)':
System.component.win32exception
line 80 in processExt.cs
access denied "**

I belive I checked all the requisitations:

1. Downloaded SeleniumBasic v2.0.9.0 - https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases
2. Installed
3. Downloaded the ChromeDriver 96.0.4664.45 - https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/ (My chrome version is *96.0.4664.93 64 bits*
4. Replaced the ChromeDriver 96 on the folder of Selenium Basic
5. In VBA I checked de Reference Selenium Type Libarary.
6. I already have a .NETF RAMEWORK 3.5 installed.

I would like to use google chrome in the same way as internet explorer to aumotate some tasks at my work.
I would appreciate any help with this problem or how setting up selenium properly.

Ps: Sorry about any grammar mistakes. haha